# How to use one to many relation in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm beginning to use Laravel Model relationship. But now I don't know how to used that relationship as below function

```
 class Notification extends Model{

   public function getNotification() {

        return self::select('*')->join('users','users.id','=','Notification.n_user_id')->get();
    }
   }
```

Comment: In what `Class` is you `getNotification()`  under?

Comment: I have used it in model

Comment: I mean what `model class`? is it in `User` model? any way I have created an answer below try and look at it. I guessed that the `getNotification()` method is in `User` Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the Notifications for the User.
     */
    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Notification');
    }
}
```

But I see in your code that the foreign key field of User ID is named `n_user_id` you should changed it to `user_id` to link them

How to use:

```
$notifications = App\Post::find(1)->notifications;

foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
    //
}
```

here is a useful [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in Laravel 5.2 Docs

**Bonus:**

You can also get the User of the notification:

```
class Notification extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the User that owns the Notification.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following way and hope it'd be helpful.

```
public function getNotification() {
    $data = DB::table('users')
            ->join('Notification', 'users.id', '=', 'Notification.n_user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'Notification.*')
            ->where('users.id', '=', 5)
            ->get();
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: NOO,
I want to change from those to eloquent